# Has anyone already implemented/ported Prevalence/Prevaylor to Javascript/NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, prevayler

Is there an SSJS implementation of the [Prevalence](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-objprev/) System Design Pattern, as implemented in Java by [Prevaylor](http://www.prevayler.org/), but for [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented it myself.

http://www.barricane.com/barricane-db/

GitHub - https://github.com/chrisdew/barricane-db

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation: https://github.com/karlwettin/prevalence-nodejs

Comment: Looks really promising. I would like to create a object store server in js using node. Can you Skype at some point? Would love to discuss taking this idea further